# Right-side of center-positioned div cut off on mobile

Tags: html, css, centering

I want to achieve a menu bar whose background extends to the length of the browser window, while the actual menu is centered in the middle. I have the following CSS code to achieve this:

```
.menuContainer {
    position:               relative;
    height:                 60px;
    width:                  100%;
    margin-top:             60px;
    padding:                0px;
    z-index:                2;
    background-color:       white;
}

.menuContent {
    position:               relative;
    width:                  1000px;
    height:                 40px;
    top:                    10px;
    margin-left:            auto;
    margin-right:           auto;
    text-align:             center;
    font-family:            Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    color:                  black;
    font-size:              12px;
}
```

This solution works fine in all major web browsers, but when I view it on iPad, the right-side of the container gets cut off at about 3/4 of the browser window. What is interesting is that, if I change the position of the container to 'fixed,' it works just fine, but unfortunately that is not what I need. I need this menu to scroll with the page's content.

Any idea what I did wrong?

**UPDATE 1.:**

I think I am zeroing in on the problem. After trying all your suggestions, including getting rid of the inner div, as well as playing with the width, I realized what the problem might be:

The container automatically inherits the width of the browser window, which on iPad is around 1000 pixels. But I have elements on the webpage that are wider than that, stretching the content area above a 1000 pixels. So, while the content of the webpage is stretching just fine, the 100% width element remains the width of the original browser window at about 1000 pixels and do not updates automatically like it does on desktop browsers. what baffles me, however, is why isn't 'fixed' positioning affected by this? I am trying to use min-width at the moment to fix this problem.

Comment: why do you need a fixed width of 1000px for .menuContent?

Comment: Because I put the menu elements inside that container, and it is much easier to position those if I work with a center-aligned container of fixed width.

Comment: you can align to center by using `width:99%; margin: auto` without specific width, this 1000px width imho is what causing the 3/4 cutoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own questions, but the problem was what I described in my update. Basically the 100% width does not update automatically on mobile browsers, meaning that, if an element is wider than the default width of the browser, 100% width elements will be cut off. I solved this by adding:

```
min-width: 1200px;
```

where the 1200px is the width of the widest element on my page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fixed width value in `.menuContainer`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Holybreath/p6QLt/2/)